# Singularity Container: I cannot make writable persistent from singularity sandbox to host

Tags: bind, singularity-container

I do the following

1. I build a sandbox

   `singularity build --sandbox project/ project.recipe`
2. I access the sandbox to modify stuff

   `singularity shell -B /path/to/host:/path/in/sandbox --writable project`
3. I build the image from the sandbox

   `singularity build project.sif project`

However my changes are not updated. in `path/to/host`, it is modified but in `/path/to/sandbox` nothing changes. Since I build the image from the sandbox eventually my changes are not shown in the .sif file. btw `/path/to/host/` =  `/path/in/sandbox`. If I omit the bind mount then it is modified in the sandbox and I can build the image with the modifications but then the file is no longer updated in the host.
**I want to access the sandbox and the able to modify both, the sandbox and the host**